# If there is any character after "," then press <space> between them

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some strings like these:

```
$str = "it is a test,it is a test";
$str = "it is a test ,it is a test";
$str = "it is a test, it is a test";
$str = "it is a test , it is a test";
```

Now I want this for all of them:

```
$str = "it is a test, it is a test";
```

---

Now, I can do that in several steps:

1. `str_replace(" , ",",","$str");`
2. `str_replace(" ,",",","$str");`
3. `str_replace(", ",",","$str");`
4. `str_replace(",",", ","$str");`

Then the output will be what I want. Now I want to know, is there any REGEX code for doing that in one step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this and replace it with `,[space]`

```
\s*,\s*
```

that is:

```
preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ', ', $str);
```

Comment: He wants to add a space after the comma, so replace to should be `, `. (comma and space)

Comment: Yes I know, I put there it didn't came.I will edit it.

Comment: Thanks.. Worked correctly. (btw, you can replace `$string` with `$str` ;-)). +1

Comment: You know what is equivalent with `\s*,\s*` in MySQL ? `REPLACE()`